# (Electron) How to get the position of a draggable element in a smaller div and translate that to a large div

Tags: javascript, electron, drag-and-drop

I'm creating an Electron program that loops a video comprising of adverts. The video spans the entire window. Let's call this window **A**.

There is a second, smaller window used to configure aspects of window A. Let's call this window **B**.

The purpose of window B is to control aspects of window A in real time, such as overlaying a message over the video or hiding the video controls. Here's an image to explain further: [image: Example to support the question]

Seen in the photo above, there is a further window open displaying a smaller video. Let's call this window **C**. The blue rectangle can be dragged around and represents a message that will be display over the video on window A.

If I save the coordinates of that rectangle and create an element on the window A video, the coordinates don't match up due to the difference in window sizes. What I can't figure out is how to take the coordinates in window C and apply them to window A correctly. I've tried working with `clientWidth`/`clientHeight` and messing with numerous CodePen's to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calculate the scale difference between the two rectangles (so is one 1.5x bigger, 1.6x bigger etc) and then apply that scale factor to the coordinates. So if the smaller window is 1.5 times smaller then you multiply the coordinates by 1.5.

Comment: @sychordCoder I'm not that good with math, how would I do that?

Comment: If they are the same ratio in width and height you take the area of the bigger divided by the area of the smaller. If they are not, big width/small width (this is the width scale) and big height/little height (this is the height scale)

Comment: If you provide some skeleton code it would be easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pixel in the smaller div equals X pixels in the bigger div. That's the ratio to multiply with. Let's assume mouse movement inside smaller div is like dragging and affecting the bigger div.

```js
var small = document.querySelector(".small");
var big = document.querySelector(".big");
var rectangle = document.querySelector(".rectangle");

var ratioX = big.clientWidth / small.clientWidth
var ratioY = big.clientHeight / small.clientHeight

small.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev) {
  var mx = ev.offsetX
  var my = ev.offsetY

  rectangle.style.left = mx * ratioX + "px"
  rectangle.style.top = my * ratioY + "px"
})
```

```css
.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.big {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Mouse over this:
<div class="small">
</div>

Will move this:
<div class="big">
  <div class="rectangle">
  </div>
</div>
```